# Output of SharePointWebControls:LookupField inside an <a> Tag?

Tags: lookup-column, aspx, syntax

I have a lookupfield which is containing an E-Mail Adress and want to have it inside an  Tag.

How is this Possible?

Like:

```
<a href="mailto:<SharePointWebControls:LookupField FieldName="b0d8fc62-4160-4a62-a594-ac4deb6f33ec" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:LookupField>">E-Mail</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a reference to the internal column name wrapped in curly braces

```
<a href="mailto:{@InternalColumnName}">Email</a>
```

The internal name is different from the display name. To find the internal name, navigate to your list settings page, then right click on the column name, scroll down through the complete url until you see "title=" and then copy and paste everything after that.  Lookup columns inject underscores and percent symbols all over the place so they often don't match the display names.